# How can I intercept (not just monitor) HTTP requests/responses so that I can edit the contents before they're sent/received?

Tags: windows-7, http, http-proxy

I am trying to intercept HTTP responses from requests sent by my web browser so that I can edit the response before it is received by the browser. More specifically, I want to modify a JS file by replacing it with a local file. Chromium browsers have local overrides, but these only work when DevTools is open and there also appears to be a memory leak issue when trying to edit very large JS files (it happens in Chrome, Brave, Edge, and even Canary).

What I am looking to do is be able to input a URL or URL pattern. When a request's URL matches the pattern, I want to be able to intercept the response by replacing it with a local file.

Note, this is different than simply monitoring incoming/outgoing traffic. I don't want to monitor. I want to intercept the traffic so that I can edit it before it's sent/received. The client application can have no knowledge of the intercept.

I am using Windows 7. I am also a c# developer, so I'd be able to write my own if there is a means to capture that data through .NET.

Comment: fiddler? https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Burp Suite? https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload

Comment: Can Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey in the browser work? Then don't try to change the JS itself but change the html which includes the JS by changing it to the local JS-file.

Comment: @Rik I have actually been trying Chromium's local overrides, but there seems to be a bug that causes editing very large resource files (js in this case) to hang the browser. It does it in Chrome, Brave, Edge, and even Canary. I could try your solutions, but I suspect it will end in the same way which is why I am trying the approach of serving the resource file via intercept so that I can edit it before the browser receives it.

Comment: @Rik I also tried editing the HTML to point to a local file, but Brave wouldn't allow it (I wasn't thinking that would work). The other option would be to serve it through IIS, but I'd need to create an SSL certificate which is a rabbit hole that I may explore as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Web requests use now almost exclusively done using the HTTPS protocol,
so you need an SSL proxy for intercepting web requests.

One such man-in-the-middle SSL proxy is the
[Charles Web HTTP proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/):

> Charles can be used as a man-in-the-middle HTTPS proxy, enabling you
> to view in plain text the communication between web browser and SSL
> web server.
>
> Charles does this by becoming a man-in-the-middle. Instead of your
> browser seeing the server’s certificate, Charles dynamically generates
> a certificate for the server and signs it with its own root
> certificate (the Charles CA Certificate). Charles receives the
> server’s certificate, while your browser receives Charles’s
> certificate. Therefore you will see a security warning, indicating
> that the root authority is not trusted. If you add the Charles CA
> Certificate to your trusted certificates you will no longer see any
> warnings – see below for how to do this.
>
> Charles still communicates via SSL to the web server. The
> communication is SSL (encrypted) from web browser to Charles and also
> SSL (encrypted) from Charles to the web server.

Comment: Does this support intercepting responses so that I can modify them before they're received by the client? Also, this looks to be a 30-day trial with licenses costing $50. Therefore, I won't be exploring Charles as a solution, though I am sure it may help someone else down the road.

Comment: Sorry, it was free when I used it many years ago. See alternatives at https://alternativeto.net/software/charles/

Answer (score 0):

man-in-the-middle SSL proxy is only one way to solve this issue. There might be browser add-ons that can do this. Firefox add-on Tamper Data was able to intercept requests for example, not sure if it could tamper responses as well. Sadly, this add-on was one of the many add-ons that Mozilla left behind with the "Quantum Break" (Firefox 57 aka Quantum which dropped support for all add-ons but WebExtensions). The new Tamper Data add-on cannot do that anymore. I am am not sure whether this is possible at all with the current WebExtension APIs in modern browsers or not and if so whether it is intentionally not possible or might be worth requesting API functionality, which is at least possible for Firefox (I dont know whether requesting new WebExtension APIs is possible for Chrome-based browsers).